# How to color set of table rows using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a table sorted by date (some dates may be missing).

So I want to color the first set of date with one color and other set of date with another.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                var oldText=''; 
                $("#managed_table_1 tr").each(function() { //loop over each row                 
                var newText = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();  //check value of TD
                if(newText == oldText){
                    $(this).css('background-color','#000');
                    oldText = newText;
                }else{
                    $(this).css('background-color','#ddd');
                    oldText = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();;

                }
            });
```

Suppose the first three rows have same delivery date then I want to color those rows as black and next two have same delivery date then I want to color those with white and then black and then white.
How could I achieve this?

Comment: what you have try so far? post your code here.

Comment: What type does your table have maybe show some code

Comment: Can you share your code? Try creating css classes based on your set.

Comment: The data is loaded through ajax

Comment: $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    var oldText=''; 
    $("#managed_table_1 tr").each(function() { //loop over each row     
       var newText = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();  //check value of TD
    if(newText == oldText){
     $(this).css('background-color','#000');
     oldText = newText;
    }else{
     $(this).css('background-color','#ddd');
     oldText = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();;
     
    }
   });

Comment: could u provide the html part or provide a fiddle which would be helpful

Comment: i am loading data thorugh datatable serverside processing

Comment: whats the problem with your current code..??

Comment: Suppose the first three rows have same delivery date then i want to color those rows as black and next two have same delivery date then i want to color those with white and then black and then white.

Comment: are the dates in ascending or descending order..??

Comment: i am using order by clause so dates are in asc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mate.Before you copy paste the code please do try to understand it mate.. :)

```
$("tr").not(':first').each(function () { //loop over each row  
   var currentdate=$(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
   var prevDate = $(this).prev().find("td:eq(0)").text(); 
   if(prevDate != currentdate){
            if($(this).prev().hasClass('pink')){
                $(this).addClass('grey');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('pink');
            }
        }else{
            if($(this).prev().hasClass('pink')){
                $(this).addClass('pink');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('grey');
            }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmc0th9t/)

Comment: Excellent sir i would sure try to understand what you did.